# converting string date to datetype in pyspark rdd

Tags: xcode

1. I need to convert string date to date in a rdd in pyspark shell
2. I have date in this format "01JAN2018:00:00:00" in date column. I need to convert this to any date format

   dq1= dq.withColumn("record_date",dq['D_MTHLY_LABEL'].cast(DateType())).show()
3. It displays null values in the new column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below example.

```
dq.selectExpr("cast(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(D_MTHLY_LABEL, 'ddMMMyyyy:HH:mm:ss'))) as date) record_date").show()
```

Comment: Hi Kaushal.. thanks its working. I have one more question on retaining the existing columns in my rdd. I have few more columns like EmpID, Salary in my rdd "dq". Can I retain these variables in the same rdd or do i need to create new rdd. the above expression is showing only the new column that got created. Can you help me.

Comment: First of all above code returns dataframe not rdd. and you can add your remaining columns as another arguments.

`dq.selectExpr("cast(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(D_MTHLY_LABEL, 'ddMMMyyyy:HH:mm:ss'))) as date) record_date", "EmpID", "Salary").show()`